# One exit button should remove any of the three players

Tags: javascript, html, css

How it should work is, if any of the three players are on, clicking on that one exit button should turn it off. removePlayer

If I click on the first play, than the middle exit button it should be removed.

Click on full page to see 3 players.

code https://jsfiddle.net/naov2phk/

This part of the code would need to be changed to something else. I think this part of the code needs to be changed for it to work properly.

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    const container = el.closest(".container");
    const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
    if (wrapper.player) {
      return removePlayer(wrapper);
    }
  }
```

This is the code I am trying to fix: https://jsfiddle.net/zj16asr2/

I would want any of the 3 players to be able to be removed from that 1 exit button on the screen.

The code I posted on here is a small reproducible example.

```js
function addPlayerHandler(evt) {
  const play = evt.target;
  play.closest(".wrap").player = {};
  play.disabled = true;
}

function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
  const el = evt.target;
  const container = el.closest(".container");
  const wrapper = container.querySelector(".wrap");
  if (wrapper.player) {
    return removePlayer(wrapper);
  }
}

function removePlayer(wrapper) {
  wrapper.querySelector(".play").disabled = false;
  delete wrapper.player;
  console.log("removePlayer");
}

for (let curtain of document.querySelectorAll(".curtain")) {
  curtain.querySelector(".play").addEventListener(
    'click',
    addPlayerHandler,
  );
  curtain.querySelector(".exit").addEventListener(
    'click',
    removePlayerHandler,
  );
}
```

```css
.curtain {
  border: solid;
}

.play[disabled]::after {
  content: " - Now Playing";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button">Exit</button>
  </div>

  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="video"></div>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, there are 2 possibilities:

1. You name each player with unic ID in you HTML. When you click on player1, you remove button of player2.
2. If you prefer to stay with generic class, when click is fired:

```
let els_curtain = document.querySelectorAll('.curtain')
```

You loop through this node list, if button from curtain 1 fired the click, you select curtain 2 and delete the button

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle link working using a generic class?

Comment: Hello, I checked your code. In fact you have kind of unic element per player: playa, playb, playc. So why not when you click button "playa", you just search playb, from this element playb, you search "closest" curtain, and from this curtain you search ".exit" and remove it